# Swift: Rounding float to nearest custom multiplier

Tags: swift

I am creating a function that rounds a view frame's CGFloat to its nearest discrete value based on a custom variable granularity.

For example, if my granularity (multiplier) was 0.25, I am trying to create a function that takes an input of 0.3 and returns 0.25, or 3.89 and returns 4.00 (closes multiple of 0.25). As of now, I've found several posts on how to round to the nearest decimal, but they don't seem to apply in this case.

```
let x = 1.23556789
let y = Double(round(1000*x)/1000)
print(y) //This removes all decimals but three, but only seem to work with multiples of 10.
```

Any idea on how I could go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the same approach as rounding to a power of 10 here.

When you want to round to the nearest 0.1, you multiply by 10, round, then divide by 10. When you want to round to the nearest 0.01, you multiply by 100, round, then divide by 100.

See the pattern here? The number you multiply and divide by is always 1 over the granularity!

So for the granularity of 0.25, you multiply and divide by 4:

```
print(round(0.3 * 4) / 4)
// or
print(round(0.3 / 0.25) * 0.25)
```

More generally, given a `granularity: Double` and a number to round `x: Double`, we can round it like this:

```
let rounded = round(x / granularity) * granularity
```

Answer (score 3):

for me it works

for rounding of a value to the multiple of 5

```
var value: Double = 32.2
print("Value:", round(value / 5) * 5)
```

outPut = Value: 30.0

Similarly, for rounding of a value to multiple of 8

```
var value: Double = 37.2
print("Value:", round(value / 8) * 8)
```

outPut: Value: 40.0
and so on...