# Using numpy take the inputs and return points that cross the x-axis

Tags: python, numpy, math

I got this question. Write a function **cos_x_crossings(begin, end, skip)**, where the input parameters are entered and returns x-points as a list that crosses the x-axis.(x-value that just before it crosses)
I am not allowed to use for or while loop.
Required to use NumPy.

test 1

```
import math
ans = cos_x_crossings(0, 4 * math.pi, 0.01)
for val in ans:
    print(round(val, 2))
```

result 1

```
1.57
4.71
7.85
10.99
```

test 2

```
import math
ans = cos_x_crossings(0, 2 * math.pi, 0.1)
for val in ans:
    print(round(val, 2))
```

result 2

```
1.5
4.7
```

Comment: What's the question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we already know that *cos(x)* is zero if and only *x* is of the form *pi/2 + k pi*, all you have to do is call `numpy.arange` with the correct parameters to generate the output array.

```py
import numpy as np

def cos_x_crossings(xstart, xstop, xstep):
  ystart = (np.trunc((xstart - np.pi/2) / np.pi) + 0.5) * np.pi
  ystop = xstop
  ystep = np.pi
  return (np.arange(ystart, ystop, ystep) // xstep) * xstep

print( cos_x_crossings(0, 4 * np.pi, 0.01) )
# [ 1.57  4.71  7.85 10.99]

print( cos_x_crossings(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.1) )
# [1.5 4.7]
```

Explanation:

- `ystart` is the smallest number of the form *pi/2 + k pi* above `xstart`; it is calculated by rounding down `xstart - pi/2` to a multiple of *pi*.
- The effect of `np.trunc( ... / pi) * pi` and `(... // xstep) * xstep` is only rounding; the division is canceled by the multiplication; see for instance [Rounding float to nearest custom multiplier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991815/swift-rounding-float-to-nearest-custom-multiplier).